# Record is overriding instead of adding new row on jtable after adding new value

Tags: java, swing, list, jtable

I have following code, which I am implementing to update `jTable` after adding value on list. I need to add row on `jtable` but it is overriding on first row. It should keep first value and add new value in new row. But not being like this. Any idea to resolve my problem.

```
private void populateTableByRecentlyAddedSubjectName(String subjectName) {
    Vector<String> tableHeaders = new Vector<String>();
    Vector tableData = new Vector();
    tableHeaders.add("Subject Name");

    java.util.List<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    Subject subject = new Subject();
    subject.setSubjectName(subjectName);
    subjectList.add(subject);

    if (subjectList != null) {
        for (Subject subjectObj : subjectList) {
            Vector<Object> obj = new Vector<>();
            System.out.println("Name " + subjectObj.getSubjectName());
            obj.add(subjectObj.getSubjectName());

            tableData.add(obj);
        }
    }
    subjectListTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subjectListTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders));
```

Looks to me like you are creating a new TableModel every time, so obviously the data is being replaces.

> I need to add row on jtable

You updated the existing data in the table by updating the data in the TableModel. So you code should be something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.addRow(....);
```

Comment: @KalathokiL., it looks to me like you are trying to add an ArrayList to the TableModel. That is NOT the way it works. All you need to do is add the String from the text field. If all of a sudden the column names changes from a single heading to 4 different column names then somewhere in your code you are changed the TableModel of the table. It is up to you to do some basic debugging. There is no way we can help you with this, because we don't have access to your code. If you need more help then post a proper `SSCCE`, not just a few random lines of code.

Comment: Sir code is full. This is not random line of code. Just I am not adding entity class Subject. **Any new Idea (Other than this) to overcome my requirement?**.

Comment: @KalathokiL. `Sir code is full. This is not random line of code.` yes it is random lines of code. How can I compile and execute that code. Search the forum if you don't know what a `SSCCE`. I can't offer any more help if you don't provide any more information.

Comment: Sir. Now you can copy past and run on your system. Hope now I will get exact solution

Comment: @KalathokiL. Where is your code that uses the addRow(...) method like I suggested in my initial answer? Why did you initially create the DefaultTableModel to how 4 columns when you only want one column? I suggest you learn how to use the IDE properly. I don't use an IDE so I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks, Yes exactly tableModel was initializing everytime.